# Loop though json key to check if its value is empty

Tags: jquery, json, performance

I have this json object. Json key `remarks` and `address` is empty. If its empty then json prints `undefine` when extracting json. But i want replace empty json with `-` sign. I know I can use:

```
 if(msg.hasOwnProperty('remarks')== ""){
        alert("A");
   }
```

But how to loop through all the keys and check if its empty and replace with `-` rather than checking it individually.

```
[
{
    "id": "224",
    "booking_id": "1",
    "room_type": null,
    "no_of_rooms_booked": null,
    "check_in_date": "2014-12-23",
    "check_out_date": "2014-12-24",
    "room_id": "93",
    "hotel_id": "9",
    "status": "1",
    "user_id": "15",
    "payment_type": "",
    "payment_status": "",
    "hotelname": "sample hotel",
    "hoteladdress": "sample address",
    "hotelcontact": "056533977",
    "Id": "224",
    "full_name": "Hom Nath Bagale",
    "address": "",
    "occupation": "Student",
    "nationality": "Nepali",
    "contact_no": "9845214140",
    "email": "bhomnath@salyani.com.np",
    "remarks": "",
    "total_amount": "5000",
    "child": "0",
    "adult": "1",
    "verification_code": null,
    "roomname": "sample room2",
    "roomprice": "1.5",
    "roomdescription": "this is for demo",
    "roomimage": "2.jpg"
}]
```

Comment: use the `for(var key in x)` loop

Comment: how to loop through all the json

Comment: see:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/loop-through-javascript-object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
data.forEach(function (el) {
  Object.keys(el).forEach(function (property) {
    if (el[property] === '') {
      el[property] = '-';
    }
  });
});
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/bineku/1/edit?js,console)

> [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) - returns an array of a given object's own
>   enumerable properties

Comment: @Homnath Bagale as I see `remarks` there is in result

Comment: @Homnath Bagale if you need check if property is undefined you can try this http://jsbin.com/bineku/2/edit?js,console

Answer (score 3):

Do

```
  var msg=
    {
        "id": "224",
        "booking_id": "1",
        "room_type": "",
        "roomimage": "2.jpg"
    };

 $.each(msg, function(k, v) {
         if(v===""){
           alert(k + ' is empty' + v);  
           //do actions
         }else{
            alert(k + ' is ' + v);
          }
    });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/singhakash07/d91jaq1L/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop to iterate through each property like

```
for (var key in msg) {
    if (msg.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if (msg[key] === '') {
            msg[key] = '-'
        }
    }
}
```

Since you have used jQuery, you could also use the [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) method like

```
$.each(array, function (i, msg) {
    $.each(msg, function (key, value) {
        if (value === '') {
            msg[key] = '-'
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Below I have provided 2 functions, **first** of which **can handle your entire json**. The **second** is **a much simpler one where you have to pass a specific element from your array** (since you know the keys you look for are only available in the first element of the array).

Speciality of **both these solutions** is that **they don't modify (mutate) the original json** which you pass to them.

```
var sampleJson = [{
  "id": "224",
  "booking_id": "1",
  "remarks": "",
  "address": "",
}];

var newJson = getNonEmptyArry(sampleJson);
var newObj = getNonEmptyObj(sampleJson[0]);

console.log('newJson: ' + JSON.stringify(newJson));
console.log('newObj: ' + JSON.stringify(newObj));
console.log('Original Json ' + JSON.stringify(sampleJson));

function getNonEmptyArry(json) {
  var cpyJson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json));
  cpyJson.forEach(obj => {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
      if (obj[key] === '') {
        obj[key] = '-';
      }
    });
  });
  return cpyJson;
};

function getNonEmptyObj(obj) {
  var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    if (obj[key] === '') {
      obj[key] = '-';
    }
  });
  return obj;
};
```